# Web part editor script in Shp Content Type

Tags: web-part, content-type, document-set

I've created a content type with several document sets inside.

I have got the necessity of creating for each document set a place like a wiki with all the information about the project.

I've thought about a web part EDITOR SCRIPT for each document set, so I've written my HTML text, my javascript function, and my personal style CSS inside an accordion and everything is working well but the problem is that this accordion is replicated in every document set inside this content type.

In which way I could have one accordion for project 1 with its own data that does not depend on the content type rule, one for project 2 with its own data, one for project 3 with its own data, and so on?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could have this accordion menu(?) as a Content Editor Web Part which fetches its content from a SharePoint-list e.g. via REST API. Then you can either create a link list for each project, or one big list with a metadata-field which determines the project and acts as a field to use for filtering. It will require some manual set up each time a project's Document Set is created, but technically works.

Comment: Hi Moe, thanks for your answer. No i don't have a list, i've have copied the data from documents inside the folders in the doc set.

Comment: here's my fiddle with the example: https://jsfiddle.net/Marcello_Mizu74/s6hx79h5/1/

Comment: i have 10 different document set in this content type, one for each project and for each one a want to have my referral accordion